# Minimum rank of the operators in a neighborhood

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Do we have any result that could say something like: "If you have an operator $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ with certain rank (possibly infinite) and if you take $\epsilon>0$ small then all the operators in $B(T;\epsilon)$ has rank at least ***something***" ?